# PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions slows down app

Tags: ios, facebook, cocos2d-iphone, parse-platform, spritebuilder

Calling PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions or PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissionsInBackground is causing my app (a game using Spritebuilder/Cocos2d v3) to slow down and become unresponsive.

I assumed I was having the issue with using the Parse Local DataStore. However, updating to 1.6.2 did not fix the problem and disabling the Local Datastore has no effect. Could it be something to do with the app transitioning to/from the Facebook App/webpage for verification on login? Is there a way to log in to Parse/Facebook without leaving the app? Or are there any known issues with Parse/Facebook and Spritebuilder/Cocos2d?

```
NSArray *permissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
if (!user) {
    NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
} else if (user.isNew) {
    NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
    [[GameState sharedGameState] savePFUser];
} else {
    NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
    [[GameState sharedGameState] FBactivate];
}
```

I have isolated this method as the cause of the issue. The login is successful and the app saves data to the Parse database. After logging in and quitting out of the app, on returning to the app I use the saved session and have no problems accessing the Facebook Graph and the Parse database. Even if I remove my `savePFUser` and `FBactivate` calls, then the issue still occurs.

EDIT: I found the solution. It was the applicationDidBecomeActive method, called when returning from the Facebook login. I needed to call the CCAppDelegate super implementation of applicationDidBecomeActive: [Using applicationDidBecomeActive makes app lag and slow after awakening it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946665/using-applicationdidbecomeactive-makes-app-lag-and-slow-after-awakening-it)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
NSArray *permissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
```

To:

```
NSArray *permissions = @[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_friends"];
```